# Referencing arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code currently writes data to a file like this:

```
1   1.64    -0.76
2   2.365   0.39
3   6.48    0.88
4   10.45   -0.75
5   12.12   -0.33
6   15.39   0.85
7   19.32   -0.73
8   24.24   0.92
9   26.73   0.35
10  28.18   -0.75
11  33.14   0.85
12  37.02   -0.74
13  37.19   -0.35
14  41.9    0.9
15  45.81   -0.85
16  50.48   0.34
17  50.71   0.84
18  54.61   -0.71
19  59.53   0.88
```

Now I want to reference it for manipulation, for instance print only column 3. I tried:

```
f = open('./gilly.txt', 'r')
print f[2]
```

but it did not work... suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Files can only be read line by line, so you have to read all of it. If you only need one column, you can do:

```
with open('gilly.txt') as myfile:
    third = [float(line.split()[2]) for line in myfile]
```

(note the conversion to `float`).

Or you can read the whole file into a list of lists:

```
with open('gilly.txt') as myfile:
    lists = [line.split() for line in myfile]
```

Sometimes you don't need to build a list at all:

```
with open('gilly.txt') as myfile:
    tuples = (map(float, line.split()) for line in myfile)
```

This should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

To read the whole file into a datastructure:

```
data = [x.strip ().split () for x in open ('gilly.txt') ]
```

Or to get the floats

```
data = [ [float (y) for y in x.strip ().split () ] for x in open ('gilly.txt') ]
```